# Flutter 1.22.2 navigation pop transition duration not matching push

Tags: flutter

I have just recently upgraded to Flutter 1.22.2 and saw some differences even though Flutter release notes indicated that navigation system remains the same.

I have 2 pages and I use push method to transition from the 1st page to the 2nd page. I have added a Transition Duration from 1st to 2nd page (code below). Prior to this version, when I pop from 2nd page to 1st page, the delay is matching the 1st to 2nd page. After the update, the when I pop from 2nd page to 1st page, the animation is very fast.

Code:

```
Navigator.push(
      context,
      PageRouteBuilder(
        transitionDuration: Duration(seconds: 1),
        pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) => goto2ndPage(),
        transitionsBuilder: (_, animation, __, child) => FadeTransition(
          opacity: animation,
          child: child,
        ),
      ),
    );
```

For pop:

```
            onPressed:
                () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
          ),
```

Can someone advice how I can delay the pop transition from 2nd page to 1st page?

Answer (score 0):

add reverseTransitionDuration to your navigation push.